# Jquery Ajax Call Error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using jQuery and using the ajax function, what causes it to use the error function? HTTP statuses?

Could the error function run if there is intermittent connectivity issues?

The issue I am seeing is that everything get successfully executed but for some reason it still will show the ERROR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `error` method will get called if the requested URL returns a 4xx or 5xx [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_http_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). You should check out the actual status code you're getting using a HTTP debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: +1 In addition to HTTP errors, the [documentation for `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) also lists "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror" as possible causes. It seems plausible that "intermittent connectivity issues", to quote the OP, might cause a timeout or abort.